# How to view own page view history on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since page view history helps to find what I had visited previously and gives the quick access to pages I've visited before.

I am wondering is there any way to view what pages I have visited previously on Stack Overflow?

I mean something like this:

[image: Search Web History on Stack Overflow]

Comment: There isn't right now... Your browser's history is probably the best way to get to it. I'm not sure there's much benefit in tracking it on the site as well, or at least mine would be noisy as hell cause I keep jumping between different sites and different questions in a large many different tabs.

Comment: Nick answer on the linked post is also relevant for this request.